# How to shuffle a dataframe column wise, but independent of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation

In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503439/651779 it is shown how to shuffle a dataframe row- and column wise. I am interested in shuffeling column wise. From the original dataframe

```
> df1
  a b c
1 1 1 0
2 1 0 0
3 0 1 0
4 0 0 0
```

shuffling column wise

```
> df3=df1[,sample(ncol(df1))]
> df3
  c a b
1 0 1 1
2 0 1 0
3 0 0 1
4 0 0 0
```

However, I would like to shuffle each row on its columns independent of the other rows, instead of shuffling the complete columns, so that you could get something like

```
>df4
  c a b
1 0 1 1
2 1 0 0
3 1 0 0
4 0 0 0
```

Now I do that by looping over each row, shuffling the row, and putting it in a dataframe. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: maybe you want to look at `?apply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) { sample(x, length(x)) } ))
```

This will give you the result in matrix form. If you have factors, a mix of numeric and characters etc, be aware that this will coerce everything to character.

Comment: I think `t(apply(df1, 1, sample))` should do it.

Comment: Regarding your edit, even if they have a mixture of column types to begin with, this would be the only possible way unless they want to shuffle *within* the column types, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AnandaMahto great improvement thatnks! You are totally correct, if he is shifting between columns then he will mix the classes anyway, but I suppose, if the OP *just* had factors for example, I wanted to let them know about coercing to a new class.

Comment: That works, thanks! Howver, it does remove the column names. Is there a way to keep them, or should I re-add them after sampling?

Comment: great glad it helped. I think it is best just to add them afterwards