# Randomize sample data in R

Tags: r, sample

First assignment, totally new here.

I have a data set that is holds the GPA, GMAT and then whether a student was admitted or not. 85 records.

All I want to do is randomize the order of those 85 records so when I grab 1:65 for the training and then 66:85 for the testing data sets, the data is somewhat even throughout.

I have the following:

set.seed (85) since I want all 85 used
sample (x) x being the data with three columns I want to randomize.

It just spits out the same thing as the original.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: [How to randomize (or permute) a dataframe rowwise and columnwise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422273/how-to-randomize-or-permute-a-dataframe-rowwise-and-columnwise)

Comment: That's it! Thank you.