# Shuffle (randomize) data for each row

Tags: r, shuffle

I am trying to reorder/shuffle the values for each row of a dataframe but cannot figure out how to do this. Please see the example below:

```
df1 #original data
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  1  2  3  4  5
#2  6  7  8  9 10
#3 11 12 13 14 15
```

The resulting dataframe should look something like this (no pattern).

```
df2 #each row is randomly shuffled
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  2  4  1  5  3
#2  6 10  9  7  8
#3 15 13 11 14 12
```

I've tried using the sample() example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422273/how-to-randomize-or-permute-a-dataframe-rowwise-and-columnwise) but its not quite what I want. The "shuffle column-wise" is the most similar to what I'm trying to do but I want to perform sample() for each individual row, not the entire column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, as.list(sample(unlist(.SD))), .(rn = 1:nrow(df1))][, rn := NULL][]
```

**NOTE:** The OP mentioned in the post that it is **rowwise** sampling.

And `base R` solution:

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, sample))
```