# R: Shuffle dataframe columnwise

Tags: r, dataframe, shuffle

This link answers a part of my question: [How to randomize (or permute) a dataframe rowwise and columnwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422273/how-to-randomize-or-permute-a-dataframe-rowwise-and-columnwise).

```
> df1
  a b c
1 1 1 0
2 1 0 0
3 0 1 0
4 0 0 0
```

Column-wise shuffle gives me below output `df3`, which is reordering the columns

```
> df3 <- df1[,sample(ncol(df1))]
> df3
  c a b
1 0 1 1
2 0 1 0
3 0 0 1
4 0 0 0
```

What I want is that the column names should change as well. Row-wise and column-wise total remains the same, just the column names get reassigned. Something like `df4`. How can I achieve this?

```
> df4
  c a b
1 1 1 0
2 1 0 0
3 0 1 0
4 0 0 0
```

PS: How do I keep the `df` in its shape rows by column? when I post the question the formatting collapses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to just sample the column-names. Something like:

```
names(df) <- names(df)[sample(ncol(df))]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was great and quick help. @P Lapointe, could you please point me in the right direction for df formatting?

Comment: @Rav Although you tagged another user, what do you mean by your question?

Comment: @P Lapointe edited my question to bring the df in correct format. Please see my PS comment. I just wanted know so I don't repeat that again.

Comment: @Rav Aha. Whenever you copy-paste your data or code from R to here, just select the text and press `Ctrl + k`. Then you will see the correct format here

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot @989!