# How to let which() throw unordered values?

Tags: r

Suppose we have a data frame

```
> (df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)))
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12
```

Is there a way to let `which()` throw column numbers in an unordered form? I. e. `which(names(df) %in% c("V1", "V4", "V3"))` yielding `1, 4, 3` instead of `1, 3, 4`? Or, if there isn't, how can we achieve this most easily?

Comment: would it be acceptable to randomise the values in the dataframe? there would be a solution with `sample` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422273/how-to-randomize-or-permute-a-dataframe-rowwise-and-columnwise)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve (real world application)? And as 李哲源  says, why not `match(c("V1", "V4", "V3"), names(df))`?

Comment: Following  @李哲源 `match(c("V1", "V4", "V3"), names(df))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following comments, we can use `match()`

```
> na.omit(match(c("V1", "V4", "V5"), names(df)))
[1] 1 4
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 3
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

Application at selection /organization of columns of a data frame (special case, when a match is `NA`):

```
> df[, na.omit(match(c("V1", "V4", "V3", "V999"), names(df)))]
  V1 V4 V3
1  1 10  7
2  2 11  8
3  3 12  9
```